# Sheilos U'Tshuvos on Gemara

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, jewish-books, adult-learning, responsa

I'm preparing classes on the beginning of Bava Metziah and I would like to present the information through the lens of the Rabbonim that used the Gemara to answer Sheilos. Does anyone know of a Sefer that compiles Sheilos U'Tshuvos through that lens?

Comment: Someone check http://www.sefer.org.il/Product/9305697/%D7%A8%D7%96%D7%90-%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99---%D7%91%D7%91%D7%90-%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%90---%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97-%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%9C

Comment: I'm curious as to how broadly/narrowly you want to define "used the Gemara" in this context. Ultimately, I would guess that almost all Teshuvos are rooted in the Gemara, but I would imagine that there may often be 'layers' above the gemara for the practical application of a Teshuva (i.e. instead of a Teshuva saying "the Halacha is Y because the Gemara says X", it might say "the Halacha is Y based on an implication of how Rabbi Akiva Eiger understands the Tosfos which explains the Rashi on Gemara X").

Comment: ליקוט ראשונים בבא מציעא.   מכון להוצאת ספרי ראשונים תפרח. This I tedhuvot ridhonim following the daf. Great book

Comment: @kouty sounds answer-ish

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/37018

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/49708

Comment: @wfb thanks I edited them in to both of the below answers

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if any of these three is exactly what you are looking for, but I'm sure that they would be extremely helpful for your purposes.

1. A Sefer that often quotes various Teshuvos and their explanations of the Gemara is [Daf Al Hadaf](https://www.google.ca/search?client=opera&q=daf%20al%20hadaf&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) (edited by R. David Abraham Mendelbaum, R. Joshua Lefkowitz, and R. Abraham Noah haLevi Klein).
2. A list of Shu"t organized in the order of the Gemara, although not necessarily quoting from earlier sources, is [Chashukei Chemed](https://www.google.ca/search?client=opera&hs=b0G&ei=aqFgW9f2B6W_jwSMp5igBQ&q=chashukei%20chemed&oq=chashukei%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0.378547.379759.0.380710.10.8.0.2.2.0.261.968.2j2j2.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.8.975...0i131k1j0i131i67k1j0i10k1.0.ALx_UqGZNBM), by [Rav Yitzchak Zilberstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchok_Zilberstein).
3. As DoubleAA mentioned above, for Bava Metzia, you have the Frankel [Raza Deshabsi](https://www.google.ca/search?client=opera&q=raza%20deshabsi&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), which is an index of a huge amount of Jewish literature, including Shu"t, organized according to the Gemara.

Answer (score 6):

Hebrewbooks.org is available to everyone who is on the web. When you open the ['shas' tab](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas), There a Sefer on the mefarshim list called שדה צופים which quotes many Sheilos Uteshuvos the likes of the Radvaz, Chavos Yair, Rambam and many more. I was recently learning Nazir which has very little Mefarshim and I found a wealth of information from the above which I quoted on the daf, absolutely recommend.

Thanks to wfb, [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/37018) is the PDF on Bava Metzia.

Answer (score 4):

A popular set of seffarim written explicitly for this purpose is שערים מצויינים בהלכה by Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Brown.

His son Rabbi Chaim Elazar finished off many of the Tractates that his father left in manuscript form. The volume on Bava Metzia was one of those.